# Sorting Custom Content Types in Orchard

Tags: sorting, drag-and-drop, orchardcms-1.8

I am in the process of building a small site with Orchard 1.8.1 and am trying to figure out sorting for a custom content type. I'm already using a projection/query combination, and I know those can sort by any field, but ideally there would be a way to change the sort order of the content items within Orchard without having a numeric field definition called "Display Order". I know Orchard has drag and drop capabilities for rearranging the field order for custom content types, so is there a built-in method that would let me use drag/drop ordering for specific content item types?

The best example of this would be the page I'm building is a staff listing. The CEO/owner would obviously want to be the top, and then he'll want to put each staff member in a specific order down the page and change it easily. The "hack" I came up with is just a numeric field called Display Order, but that seems fairly archaic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your "hack" is a pretty good solution, but I don't see it as a hack. You probably have some way to indicate the position of the staff in the company, for example "Level". This way you can order the staff by the "Level" they are and another property for the second ordering.

Comment: OK, thanks! I was hoping for a built-in drag/drop option that I was missing, but if that doesn't exist then this will work. Thanks!